# Loader is returning a null object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to make a menu that calls another `swf` file when the `button` is clicked. 
however, the message returned is-

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at GameController()

The `GameController()` given above is the document class of the called `"HotAirRises.swf"`

the code is given below:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import fl.controls.Button;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

public class MainController extends MovieClip {


    public function MainController() 
    {
        tester.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testIt);
        // constructor code
    }
    private function testIt(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        trace("testing");
        var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                    
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("HotAirRises.swf"); 
        trace(myLoader,url);
        myLoader.load(url,null);
        addChild(myLoader);
    }
}

}
```

What am i missing here? something to do with the other `HotAirRises.swf` file?
Please Help!

Comment: Loader is asynchronous. You need to add an eventlistener (EVENT.COMPLETE) to Loader.

Comment: AFAIK `trace` statements don't support comma separated values. If you wish to append multiple values, you need to use `+` operator.  Can you try commenting out that `trace`?

Comment: trace do support comma separated values. adding Event.COMPLETE listener is not nessecary. Finally the problem is 'tester' is not recognized and is null.

Comment: I agree with @BotMaster, `Event.COMPLETE` listener is not necessary ( even it doesn't exist for a `Loader` object ) and `trace()` accepts comma separated values. I think that your `MainController` class is fine and the problem is in your `GameController` class ( the document class of your "HotAirRises.swf" ), so show its code to know what's the problem exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is `GameController` in HotAirRises.swf accesses the `stage` property(probably to position display objects based on stage dimensions).
The problem is that the swf is being loaded, so initially the `stage` property will be null.

You can try to add the loader straight away, before loading:

```
var myLoader:Loader = addChild(new Loader()) as Loader;
```

(and you wouldn't need `addChild(myLoader);`) after loading, but this might not work.

To be 100% sure you'll get the expected behaviour (and as a best practice), initialise your GameController on the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event handler.

Where your code could be something like:

```
GameController(){//constructor
   init();
}

private function init():void{
  //initalise Game Controller code
}
```

it should be something like:

```
GameController(){//constructor
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}
private void init():void{
//stage should not be null here, carry on initialising
}
```

Have a look at [this article](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/12/03/understand-added_to_stage-event/) as well.

Comment: Wow! It worked. Thanks Greg. your post was very insightful.